# Change PictureBox image onClick

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have 5 PictureBoxes and I want to change the image when I click on each one.
For example if the image displayed on pictureBox1 is "_1", when I click it, the image should change to "_1x" and vice versa. The code in my if clause never gets executed and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pb1.Image = Properties.Resources._1;
        pb2.Image = Properties.Resources._2;
        pb3.Image = Properties.Resources._3;
        pb4.Image = Properties.Resources._4;
        pb5.Image = Properties.Resources._10;
    }

    private void pb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pb1.Image == Properties.Resources._1)
        {
            pb1.Image = Properties.Resources._1x;
        }

        else { pb1.Image = Properties.Resources._1; }
    }
```

Comment: you need to work out a way to track which image is assigned, perhaps using the .Tag property.  `pb1.Image == Properties.Resources._1` is not going to do an image comparison; it will test of they are the same object.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it with Tag and it workes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep local reference to your image before attaching it to the Picturebox otherwise it create new object always so comparison fails.

Try This:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    Bitmap img1 = Properties.Resources._1;
    Bitmap img2 =Properties.Resources._2;
    Bitmap img3 = Properties.Resources._3;
    Bitmap img4 = Properties.Resources._4;
    Bitmap img10 = Properties.Resources._10;

    Bitmap img1x = Properties.Resources._1x
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pb1.Image = img1; //assign image1 to picturebox here
        pb2.Image = img2; 
        pb3.Image = img3; 
        pb4.Image = img4; 
        pb10.Image = img10; 
    }
    private void pb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (pb1.Image == img1)
       {
         pb1.Image = img1x ;
       }

       else { pb1.Image = img1; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works great. I have another problem, if you could help me with. My full code for onClick is :

Comment: Please read this : http://pastebin.com/x1KMGnW0

Comment: if the above code works then accept it as answer and post another new question...